# Hospitalized person in custody. Not allowed ANY FORM of communication

Tags: criminal-law, police, arrest

My wife had an altercation with her son: he shoved her and she broke her hip. We called the police because he was out of control. She tried to stop him from flattening tires on his wife's car, however the police had to arrest her since she put her hands on him first. They didn't want to but said they had to arrest her.

Now she's in hospital with 2 officers in her room. I tried to visit and got kicked out. She had booking ink on her hands and they said she was in custody. I can't call her either. I called the jail and they were no help on writing to her either. I really need to find a way to communicate with her.

The police said it will almost certainly be nolle prosed.  But I cannot find anyway to communicate with her. Also dont they only have 48 hours to hold her without formal charge?

So my question is: any ideas on communication?

I was considering serving her with some type of legal document. I think they have to allow that. Any ideas there?

My other question what about her right to a speedy trial?  She doesn't show on their system as being in custody or charged. Don't they only have 48 hours?

This is all so stupid, she is the one who called the police to begin with. She has serious medical conditions beside her hip as well.

Is there any way to establish communications?

Comment: We can't give legal advice here. This is a matter for her lawyer.

Comment: The reference to 48 hours makes me think this might be in the USA - in E&W it starts at 24, and here prisoners in police custody (including those in hospital) are not normally allowed visitors - especially those who may be a witness to the alleged offence.

Comment: The details of what right such a person has vary significantly depending on jurisdiction: what country and in the US or another federal country what state or province. But it is not unlikely that getting a lawyer is the best way to deal with such matters. On speedy trial, allowed times vary but it is more likely to be a matter od weeks or months, not days.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I believe speedy trial is supposed to be days - so short that even the defense can't prepare adequately, so *they* agree to waive speedy trial.  And IIRC there's no such thing as a 'half way waive' so once you waive, prosecution can drag it out *years*.

Comment: Sounds like part of it is keeping the mother and son *apart*. So they may have done the arrest "as a pretense" so they could get the mother protected without having to go through the procedural and budget rigmarole of justifying full police protection.

Comment: @Harper perhaps what "speedy trial" means in the US should be a new question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no jurisdiction stated in the question or tags, without which no reliable answer can be given.

Comment: That's not an appropriate reason to close a question here, as multiple meta discussions have concluded on firm rational grounds for years. It being a clear request for specific legal advice, however, is.

Answer (score 3):

The way to establish communication is through her lawyer. You may or may not have a right to talk to her while she's "in custody," but her lawyer would.